乗せる doesn't take a grammatical subject?
My understanding of Japanese grammar has been that verbs (used predicatively) always have a subject. But it seems like something is going on with 乗せる that defies this. If it were true that verbs always have subjects, then in this sentence (from 赤いくつ by Hans Christian Andersen and translated by 楠山正雄)

そのとき、年とったかっぷくのいいお年よりの奥さまをのせた、古風な大馬車が、そこを通りかかりました。


As she (the protagonist) did so, a large, antique horse-drawn carriage carrying a plump older woman passed through.

what is the subject of のせる? Is it 奥さまが奥さまを大馬車にのせた? That feels strange to me, but maybe? Is it 大馬車が奥さまをのせた? I don't think so, as I was not able to find an example of のせる used this way. It could be some unstated driver of the carriage, but that doesn't make sense to me because such a driver is never metioned or otherwise implied before or after this sentence; implying his existence here would be a non-sequitir.
So I turned to a dictionary and got more confused.（旺文社）国語辞典［第十一番］lists 乗せる explicitly as a 他動詞, and the first definition is

乗り物の中に入れる。


To place into/onto a vehicle.

Great. This makes sense to me in-and-of itself. But then the example sentence is

「駅まで自動車に―」

which doesn't clarify the situation for me. The intent of the sentence seems to be "(I) take a car to the train station", but given the definition that "I" would be marked with を, just like in my first example sentence with 奥さまを. There, again, seems to be no subject (though of course its hard to judge when this sentence has no context).
So I looked at another dictionary, （三省堂）スーパー大辞林［3.0］. Again 乗せる is a 他動詞, and the first definition is

人を乗り物に乗らせる。


To make people ride in vehicles.

Makes sense. But the first example sentence

「乗客千人を—・せた船」


A ship upon  which a thousand passengers ride

is just like my first sentence. The second example sentence

「駅まで—・せてってあげるよ」

I'm not sure I understand the meaning, so I won't comment on it. Edit: I realize now this って is probably いって (and not quotatative って, which is why I was confused), so this would be something like "I'll take you all the way to the station". So there is a subject here, though I think I would class this as a different usage than what I'm asking about because there is clearly a driver present.

So am I missing something really obvious? Maybe something less obvious? Or is 乗せる actually a verb that doesn't take a subject? If it is, are there other verbs like this in Japanese?
I think part of answering this question would be answering this one: what is the difference between 乗せる and 乗る with this usage? Is there any difference in meaning between 奥さまを乗せた大馬車 and 奥さまが乗った／乗っている大馬車?

I think actions are what matters most in Japanese, Things like subject, object, and location are secondary. Sometimes they can't be inferred by context, which is the case in your first example sentence. So it is not worth wasting your mental energy to determine who is the subject for のせた. This kind of situation also happens in English. If I give you a simple English sentence like "I played tennis," can you infer who I played tennis, where I played tennis, when did I play tennis?

@JimmyYang "So it is not worth wasting your mental energy" Why do you get to decide this for me? You're also basically saying "your question isn't worth answering". With your "play" example, you are missing the point of the question. Not every verb in English needs an indirect object, nor any of that other information. But (as far as I am aware as a native speaker), every verb in English does need a subject, even if it's implied. I thought the same was true for Japanese, and that is what my question is about.

I don't mean to say your question is useless. What I was trying to say is that unlike eurocentric languages like English where every verb needs a subject, Japanese verbs does not require subject or other secondary information like indirect object.

"(I) ride a bike to the train station". Did you misread 自動車 as 自転車? Does correcting for that get you on a better path to understanding the example sentence?

This... I think you probably want to go to Linguistics SE if you need a theoretical big picture. For Japanese, you can simply understand that 乗せる just means a vehicle "carries" someone.

Just in case the context is important to answer the question, the quote is taken from Akai Kutsu, a Japanese translation of the fairy tale The Red Shoes by Hans Christian Andersen.

@JimmyYang Can you give me other examples then, where a verb does not have an identifiable (implicit) subject?

@Leebo Oof, you're right, I did misread that, but I don't think that changes much.

@AndrewT. You're right, I should have included that. Thank you!

@broccoliforest That's my confusion though. You would think that would be 乗り物が人を乗せる, but apparently it's 乗り物に人を乗せる. My question is also about whether or not there are other verbs like this, which I think is a question that belongs on this site. But I will probably try cross-posting after a while.

@Leebo I realized that with that fix there could be some implied driver of the car, would you say that is the case?

@NicholasTodoroff naruto has already answered, but yes it is 乗り物が人を乗せる. It is quite usual that a verb has multiple case framings in any language: "I look her in the eyes" but "you look tired", in the latter you are not staring at tiredness. While why it happens is a target of interest in linguistics, as an existing language it is just how it is. I remember I answered a similar question recently.

@broccoliforest This is exactly it, and your link is 100% on point, thank you! I think my confusion was that I noticed 乗せる was being used like this, but then when I looked in dictionaries (monolingual and bilingual) the definitions didn't seem to support the vehicle being the subject. Probably a combination of my ineptitude and dictionaries not being perfect.


what is the subject of のせる?

The subject is 大馬車. Just as you can say "A carriage is carrying a woman", you can say "馬車が女性を乗せている". There is nothing tricky about it.

I was not able to find an example of のせる used this way.

I don't know how you searched for example sentences, but in BCCWJ, you can easily find numerous examples including "ロンドンから彼を乗せてきた車", "アユバを乗せた船ウィリアム号", "甘寧を乗せた小舟", "リゲル第四惑星まで彼を乗せてきた巨大戦艦" and so on.
I think you've mixed up two equally important usages of 乗せる:

AがXを乗せる means "A carries/bears X", where A is typically a vehicle but sometimes a person, table, etc. When A is a person, this includes taking someone somewhere by car or a motorcycle.
AがBにXを乗せる means "A loads/puts X onto B", where A is a person and B is a vehicle, table, counter, etc.

Monolingual dictionaries don't always explain detailed particle usages, but you have to get used to both. Either way, 乗せる is a simple transitive verb that takes a subject. (乗る is an intransitive verb.)
駅まで乗せてってあげるよ can be understood as the first usage; it's the same as 私があなたを駅まで乗せてってあげるよ, but both the subject and the object of 乗せる have been omitted. The literal translation is "I'll carry you to the station". But when someone says this, it almost certainly doesn't mean they'll give you a piggyback ride, but rather that they'll use a car or something.

I am specifically asking about usage (1), I just haven't seen evidence that you can use が here. All your examples are in attributive form. Do you have any examples where the vehicle is marked with が (preferably) or maybe は? In the first dictionary example that I gave, corresponding to your usage (1) 「駅まで自動車に乗せる」 the vehicle is already marked with に. How would you translate this sentence (perhaps in some additional context)? Would you say that there is an implied driver?

@NicholasTodoroff Did you see "馬車が女性を乗せている" in the first part of my answer?

"駅まで自動車に乗せる" is usually simply translated as "to drive (someone) to the station". (By the way, "to drive the car to the station" and "to drive you to the station" are two acceptable usages of "drive" in English, but the latter is very confusing to some learners. Japanese people never say あなたを運転する.)

Yes, I just assumed you had written that on the spot and was hoping there are other examples "in the wild".

@NicholasTodoroff The Japanese version of Dona Dona has "荷馬車がゴトゴト子牛を乗せていく". This is a song most Japanese kids learn at school or kindergarten.

Great! Thank you! I will wait some time to see if anyone has anything else to say and then accept your answer. So, would you say that from the Japanese perspective it doesn't matter so much whether it's the driver or the vehicle which is 乗せる'ing someone? That is, both 自動車の運転者が乗せる and 自動車が乗せる are equally valid?

@NicholasTodoroff They're both valid, but "I'll drive you to the station" and "The car will take you to the station" are very different.
